# Как разделять логику вертикального и горизонтального положения экрана

Tags: android

У меня есть активность (или фрагмент) с `RecyclerView`, в котором находиться 3 пункта выбора, по открытию которого, открывается окно с соответствующей надписью. Если телефон\планшет находиться в вертикальном положении, тогда я хочу отображать надпись в новом окне, а если в горизонтальном — слева `Recycler`, а справа надпись. На фото привел пример (прошу прощения за мой `paint` :D). Как правильно разделить логику (как-то волшебно управлять активностями или фрагментами, может еще что-то) поведения на вертикальное и горизонтальное положение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читайте Харди и Филлипса, "Глава 22. Двухпанельные интерфейсы". Как раз ваш вопрос раскрывается. Остальные главы тоже прочитайте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вас интересует разделение по ориентации используйте суффиксы для ваших ресурсов: `-land` `-port` естественно если вы изначально, разрабатывали ваше app под device с портретной ориентацией, то вам достаточно будет сделать папку к примеру `layout-land` и при альбомной ориентации она будет работать, в противном случае значения будут браться по default из изначальной папки, даже если нет суффикса `-port`.

При создании новой директории ресурсов в AS, очень хорошо показывает это квалификаторами `UI-mode` (могу ошибаться).

Если вы хотите ещё разделить на планшеты и телефоны, тогда с API 14 существует суффикс `sw600` - для 7-и дюймовых планшетов, и `sw800` для 10-и дюймовых планшетов. Всё работает абсолютно аналогично, тому что написано выше.

Ещё один момент, суффиксы могут записываться последовательно, и работают с определенными приоритетами, которые очень хорошо описаны в официальных guidline google. Вот нашел перевод для вас [Обзор ресурсов](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/overview.html)

Comment: Я немного не это имел ввиду. С ресурсами все понятно, но как организовать одинаковую работу в любом положении? Что для этого нужно использовать (фрагменты, активности) и как сделать их взаимодействие?

Comment: "одинаковую работу в любом положении?" у вас на картинках показана, разная работа(разметка), в разных положениях. Меня значит это сбило от сути вопроса. Вы хотите узнать как в цикле (активити или фрагмента), организовать переходы с одной разметки на другую при определенном поведении?

Comment: Да. И как прописывать логику? Сделать так, чтобы была одна активность, а два окна - просто фрагменты?

Comment: Вам нужно подробней изучить мой ответ, но я попробую ещё подробней объяснить в примере (это не значит что так обязательно):
Допустим рис.1 - у вас есть активити в котором есть список при нажатии на пункт происходит переход в др активность и отрисовывается conainer№1 с нужным фрагментом, так вот; В -land ориентации рис.2, у вас другая! разметка, где container№1 уже в активити и при нажатии на пункт Recycler он сразу же и отрисовывает нужный фрагмент в зависимости от позиции пункта, без перехода в др активность. Надеюсь немного понятней))

Comment: Тогда, при нажатии, нужно проверять в каком положении экран и тогда смотреть: создавать новую активность или помещать контейнер. Верно? Но тогда вторая активность перезапустится, во время поворота и первая активность останется невидимой.